# Javascript skipping function?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some form validation for a site registration form, I have a function which calls other functions. Each function it calls does some validation, however when it gets to the final function it skips it!

```
function validateForm() {
    if (usernameVal() === false) { return false; }
    if (emailRegexVal() === false) { return false; }
    if (emailMatchVal() === false) { return false; }
    if (pwMatchVal() === false) { return false; }
    else { return true; }
}

function usernameVal() {
    var x = document.forms['Form']['Username'].value;
    if (x === '') {
    alert('username must be filled out');
    return false;
    }
}

function emailMatchVal() {
    var x = document.forms['Form']['Email_1'].value;
    var y = document.forms['Form']['Email_2'].value;
    if (x !== y) {
        alert('Email Addresses do not match');
        return false;
    }
}

function emailRegexVal() {
    var x = document.forms['Form']['Email_1'].value;
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    var valid = regex.test(x); 
    if (!valid) {
        alert('Invalid email address!');
        return false;
    }
}

function pwMatchVal() { 
    var x = document.forms['Form']['pw1'].value;
    var y = document.forms['Form']['pw2'].value;
    if (x !== y) {
        alert('Your passwords do not match!');
        return false;
    }
}
```

So when I click the submit button, it does the username check, regex on email, the email check, then by the looks of things tries to submit the form pwMatchVal() function. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ example?

Comment: have you tried inserting `console.log("blabla");` in your code to see whether it actually skips or what js does exactly?

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/seb500/Np8L4/

Comment: Did you even try that jsfiddle to make sure it would demonstrate your problem before sharing it?

Comment: @BillRawlinson I've never used JSFiddle before, so I apologise :\

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it, if ANY of these functions return false, the *whole thing* (validateForm) will exit.  So if the second to last function returns false, then the last function will indeed not be called.

You need to call each function first, save the result, and, after each validation function has been called, *then* issue your return statement.

It should look something like this

```
function validateForm() {
    var v1 = (usernameVal() === false);
    var v2 = (emailRegexVal() === false);
    var v3 = (emailMatchVal() === false);
    var v4 = (pwMatchVal() === false);
    return v1 && v2 && v3 && v4;
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying Adam, but seeing as I can go through each function manually by entering values into the field, surely once I have entered correct values to match the criteria it will go to the 4th, instead it just skips it! And the code you provided doesnt seem to work :z

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined validation.js:38
pwMatchVal validation.js:38
validateForm validation.js:6
onsubmit

Comment: @horHAY - ok, so one of your elements isn't being found.  Find the line that that pertains to and double check your dom.

Comment: It points to line 38, which is: var y = document.forms['Form']['pw2'].value; but this works through the other js? Any ideas?